# Using the Eclipse Marketplace Client within Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio (Devstudio)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-marketplace, jboss-developer-studio

I would like to ask you whether (and how) it's possible to use Eclipse Marketplace in Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio 10.3.0.GA. I was trying to install EMPC from [1], but the version looked a bit old and didn't work afterwards. Basically I would like to install [2] to Devstudio. How can I do that? I was trying this drag and drop, but it didn't work for me.

Thank you

[1] http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/neon

[2] https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angular-ide

Answer (score 6):

You can install an entry from the Marketplace site without the Marketplace client.
When viewing an entry, click on the little arrow button located under the Install button and it will display the update site. Then use Help -> Install New Software and add the new update site

Answer (score 2):

You can't drag and drop because this feature is from **`EPP Marketplace Client`** and you don't had the plugin installed yet. Follow this steps and when the plugin is already installed you can do it.

#### Prepare first steps:

1. Go to: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-marketplace-client
2. Click inside download icon [image: Click] to choose **`Update site URL`**
3. Choose the last version **`Oxygen 4.7`**
4. Copy **`Update site URL`**http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/releases/1.6.4

#### Installing steps:

1. Open your **Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio**
2. Select **`Help`** -> **`Install New Software...`**

   [image: install]
3. Add a new site to the Eclipse Update Manager
4. Inside **`Work with:`** paste **`Update site URL`** and press `Enter`

   - **`EPP Marketplace Client`**: http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/releases/1.6.4
5. Select **`EPP Marketplace Client`**
6. Click **`next`** & accept the terms of use
7. Wait finish installation and restart the IDE when asked
8. Now **`EPP Marketplace Client`** is ready for use

---

#### Reference:

- https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-marketplace-client/help

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1.**

Install Eclipse from the rpm in Fedora or *if you're a subscriber* the RHSCL (Red Hat Software Collections) package rh-eclipse46.

Or install from an EPP package [3] such as the Java or Java EE package.

All of those should include the Marketplace Client.

**Step 2.**

Then, install devstudio 10.4 from the update site [4].

[3] https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/

[4] https://devstudio.jboss.com/10.0/stable/updates/

**Step 3.**

Fire up the Eclipse Marketplace client within Eclipse to search for the third-party add-ons you'd like to install.