# How to enable JDK 15 in Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio?

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, java-15

I'm using Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio 10.4.0.GA (also tested with CodeReady 12.17.0.GA), and would like to upgrade to JDK 15.

But even with the new version installed, it is not available to be setup as default JRE.

I tried some eclipse instructions to JDK 15 ([#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42788564/using-the-eclipse-marketplace-client-within-red-hat-jboss-developer-studio-devs) and [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64119888/how-to-use-java-version-15-in-eclipse-2020-09)), but without success with JBoss.

[image: Installed JDK 15 folder]

[image: Add JRE]

Does anyone have a tip?

Thank you

**Solution:** Use [Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17)](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/2020-09/R/eclipse-inst-jre-win64.exe)

Comment: That's a 2017 release *far* predating the *existence* of Java 15. You need a newer release than that, ideally the current one.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I tried it now with version 12.17.0.GA, but it also doesn't recognize JDK 15... only until 14. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17) with the [**Java 15 Support for Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17)**](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-15-support-eclipse-2020-09-417) installed.

Answer (score 0):

Your error same with this error: [Target is not a JDK root. System library was not found. Eclipse Oxygen 4.7 + Java9 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41029647/target-is-not-a-jdk-root-system-library-was-not-found-eclipse-oxygen-4-7-jav)

So you have to find a support extension if its existing and available.